# Countifs formula doesn't work when using array exclusion but works with inclusion

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, countif

I have a Countifs formula that filters multiple headings, and sometimes multiple criteria in a specific heading.

It doesn't work when filtering a specific heading to exclude 2 options. It works when I include.
It's easier to exclude 2 options than to include 10, it's a template so the data in the column always changes, so better to exclude just 2.

This formula includes "MA05" and "MA07", which gives the correct answer

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table15[Vendor],{"MA05","MA07"},Table15[MS],4,Table15[[      SOH DC]],">0",Table15[[      SOH]],0,Table15[RP Type],"Roster",Table15[Listing Status],"Listed",Table15[Ownership 2],"Hyper"))
```

but this one should exclude them, gives the wrong answer

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table15[Vendor],{"<>MA05","<>MA07"},Table15[MS],4,Table15[[      SOH]],0,Table15[RP Type],"Roster",Table15[Listing Status],"Listed",Table15[Ownership 2],"Hyper"))
```

I think the problem comes in with the double exclusion {"<>MA05","<>MA07"}.
I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an array you are essentially creating an OR filter, but you need an AND if you're going to exclude, which is actually simpler - you just repeat the column and additional criterion:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table15[Vendor],"<>MA05",Table15[Vendor],"<>MA07",Table15[MS],4,Table15[[      SOH]],0,Table15[RP Type],"Roster",Table15[Listing Status],"Listed",Table15[Ownership 2],"Hyper")
```